# I would like to make a query with a concatenated fields from a table in my vba code in ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox, concatenation

I have a table in my ms access database which has 1 column that says downdate and 1 column that says downtime also 1 column that says update and 1 columns that says uptime. I have a created a query that concatenated the downdate and downtime, it was created in my query as Down: [downdate] & " @ "  & [downtime] and Up: [update] & "@" &  [uptime]. 
What I wanted to do is to make another query where I can find all the records between the date from my first textbox to my second textbox with out losing the query that I have created to show up in my listbox. I really need your help everyone thanks in advance.

Comment: this is my vba code
Private Sub cmdsearch3_Click()
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
date1 = Me.txtsearchdate5
date2 = Me.txtsearchdate6
srchRowSource = "SELECT systemName AS System, bugs AS Bugs/Fixes, downdate &  " atsign " & downtime AS Down, update &  " at sign " & uptime AS UP, reportedBy AS Reported By, remarks AS Remarks, status AS Status, by AS Done By, reportId FROM tblsys WHERE downdate BETWEEN #  atsign Var1  # AND #  atsign Var2  #"
If lstsystem.ListCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "There was no report found."
End If
End Sub it is always compile error as at sign as invalid character

Comment: Please add your code to your question, and format it using the `{}` button.  Code in comments is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to filter for a date/time period, you can't use that weird string format. You must ad the date and time:

```
"Where #" & Format(date1, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# Between [downdate] + [downtime] And #" & Format(date2, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# Between [update] +  [uptime]"
```